# JSON Decode return NULL

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I make a curl request to a URL, got this JSON `$data` back

```
{"status":200,"message":"Success","data":[{"cpe_mac":"665544332211","device_mac":"223344556677","device_activity":"INACTIVE","dhcp_lease_held":"CONNECTED_DEVICE_DHCP_LEASE_NOT_AVAILABLE","ip_address":"127.0.0.3","vlan_id":1002,"hostname":"babyhost","dhcp_lease_start_time":400,"dhcp_lease_length":600,"interface":"WIRELESS","ssid":"2219","port_ranges":[{"startport":0,"endport":06000:6500}],"last_updated_utc_in_secs":1446061806668}]}
```

---

Then, I **decode** that `$raw = json_decode($data, true);`

When I print them out I got `null`

`dd($raw); // null`

---

I just want to convert that json to an array and access it.

**Any hints on this will be much appreciated !**

Comment: If you're running PHP 5.5 or better you can use `echo json_last_error_msg();` to see what the error was. Either way you must have malformed JSON.

Comment: when you work with JSON; always check it with tool like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Will do from now on. Thanks for your advise. I"m new to all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json that is returned is invalid

[image]

Comment: Would your answer provide any value if the image weren't there? Pictures should illustrate things, not be the entirety of your answer.

Comment: Yes, it illustrates where the issue is in the json

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
[{"startport":0,"endport":06000:6500}]
```

of your JSON is invalid. The `06000:6500` is not a valid property value. Once I fixed that, `json_decode` worked properly.